# STM32 interrupt pin strange behavior

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, interrupt, stm32cubeide

I am using stm32cubeide to program a stm32f030f4p6 MC. I have assigned one pin as an external interrupt and it is connected to the data output of an RF433 receiver.
Here is a summary of my code:

```
int k;
int main(void)
{
 while (1)
 {
  k=0;
 }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  k=1;
 }
```

and, the value of 'k' over time is:
[image: the value of 'k' over time("button" is the button of the rf433 transmitter)]

the value of 'k' over time("button" is the button of the rf433 transmitter)

as it can be seen from the picture, interrupt is triggered even when no signal is received.

PS. I have tried external pull down and pull pull up resistors 10k and 4.7 k did not have an effect and with 2.2k no signal from rf433 receiver would be detected.

Comment: How did you setup the GPIO EXTI interrupt exactly (falling/rising edge, internal pull-up/-down etc.)? And are there maybe interrupts happening on other pins? `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()` is usually used by all used GPIOs, so make sure to check `GPIO_Pin` and to determine the current pin state you could use`HAL_GPIO_ReadPin()`.

Comment: interrupting based on a button press is a bad idea in general. use a periodic timer interrupt to sample the pin is more reliable.

Comment: there is no reason to assume that that while loop will write 0 to k more than once.  even if you use volatile on that variable it is not assumed to work how you think it might work as that is not what volatile is really for.   unless you do not optimize the code then in that case it may just work.

Comment: @rel It is external interrupt mode with rising edge trigger detection and no pull ups and no pull downs. The other interrupt is not connected to anything.

Comment: @old_timer Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the approach you have suggested. However, my problem here is (upon my assumption) that the interrupt shouldn't be triggered without the receiver receiving any signals. And what is obvious here (apart from the approach for getting the value of 'k') that interrupt is triggered while it shouldn't be.

Comment: It was not clear to me at first how the button is connected to the STM32: It is on the transmitter board and the STM32's GPIO is connected to receiver's data out pin. So, before trying to optimize things with GPIO EXTI interrupts I would try to verify that the actual data reception works reliably (with CRC check etc.), with a loop sending out known bytes, without a button. Also try to check the data pin with a logic analyzer/DSO (signals interferring? Check with SDR). - And then do basic tests with GPIO EXTI interrupts, pull-ups, debouncing etc. on a dev board, to see the behavior isolation.

Comment: @rel thank you for the suggestions. After further examining of the the pin's behavior I realized that this actually is the right behavior of this pin (so many environment noises are received by the receiver) and these noises should be handled by the software.

Comment: @HamidRajabi Nice! Glad to hear that it works now as intended.